# windows api: how to find active thread count in current process?

Tags: multithreading, winapi

I have written a server based on boost::asio in windows platform. I want to log currently active thread count of my application at regular intervals.

I can see the thread count for my application in windows task manager's process view in Threads column. is there a windows api to get the same?

after futile googling for sometime i thought its best to seek advice from SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Raymond Chen [has the answer](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/02/23/537856.aspx), based on the [Tool Help Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686837%28VS.85%29.aspx).

For the sake of completeness, his sample code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <tlhelp32.h>

int __cdecl main(int argc, char **argv)
{
 HANDLE h = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPTHREAD, 0);
 if (h != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
  THREADENTRY32 te;
  te.dwSize = sizeof(te);
  if (Thread32First(h, &te)) {
   do {
     if (te.dwSize >= FIELD_OFFSET(THREADENTRY32, th32OwnerProcessID) +
                      sizeof(te.th32OwnerProcessID)) {
       printf("Process 0x%04x Thread 0x%04x\n",
             te.th32OwnerProcessID, te.th32ThreadID);
     }
   te.dwSize = sizeof(te);
   } while (Thread32Next(h, &te));
  }
  CloseHandle(h);
 }
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: i appreciate your quick reply on this..this is one more reason to love SO.